# How to install Windows 10 Mobile with recovery tool?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, 8.0, update, recovery-tool, lumia-640

I have a Lumia 640 that ran Windows Phone 8.1 and I updated it to Windows 10 Mobile. I dropped the phone and the system refused to start and I reinstalled it using recovery tool, but it installed an older and unknown version of Windows Phone 8 that wasn't compatible with almost any Windows app from Store. I want to install Windows 10 Mobile again using recovery tool, because I can't make updates with the phone.

On recovery I get this:

[image]

How can I upgrade my phone to Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: Why can you not make updates with the phone, @ORares

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder it says that is up to date

Comment: @ORares, have you tried the Windows Insider Programme?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder The store only shows a few apps,not even the basic apps like Messenger.I can only update if I install other version

Comment: @ORares, have you tried [the upgrade advisor](http://aka.ms/W10MUpgradeAdvisor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the Upgrade Advisor from the store to see if your phone can install the last version of Windows 10 Mobile. If it is possible, the update will start, if it is not possible you will be stuck in windows phone 8/8.1

Answer (score 2):

I FIXED THE PROBLEM NOW. One of the first things i did when getting
my phone was turning off automatic updates. after i saw the problem i
did a system restore, that fixed it temporarily but the problem came
back. but after turning on automatic updates and updating and restarting the store works fine now.

this might not help everybody, but hopefully some.